# Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException

Tags: symfony

I am trying to update composer to integrate some other api, but cli shows the error
Indentation problem at line 13 (near "   mailer_transport: smtp"). I do not know how to manage Yaml.

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
    parameters:
        database_host:127.0.0.1
        database_port:3306
        database_name:news_driver
        database_user:root
        database_password: ''
        mailer_transport: smtp
        mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
        mailer_user: null
        mailer_password: null
        secret:ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
        twitter_consumer_key:<hidden>
        twitter_consumer_secret:<hidden>
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `''` of the database password field?

Comment: yes same issue , I do not know what is going on , I also try to comment line 13 but same issue is showing

Comment: Make sure those are spaces instead of tabs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably **an indentation problem** and you also **miss a space between colons and values**. I just tried to edit it in the YAML online parser here: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Working version:

```
parameters: 
  database_host: 127.0.0.1
  database_port: 3306
  database_name: news_driver
  database_user: root
  database_password: ~
  mailer_transport: smtp
  mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
  mailer_user: null
  mailer_password: null
  secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
  twitter_consumer_key: NN51z30h469bKUJUQHesZg6CQ
  twitter_consumer_secret: qKobQPtChifrD2LxnJI512EMGHqBGmnaJ9EQI7fL9wrrXwPY8f
```

Try to copy it from here, it should work now.

Comment: Ivan I tried this but still same issue . while I removed the parameters.yml file still same issue

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a cache problem. Try to clear it (for the right environment you're using).

Comment: Hi Ivan , I got solution . composer pointing parameters.yml.dst file  for same setting as the parameters.yml setting .